# HTTP API Gateway JWT Authorizer to take identity source from cookie

Tags: cookies, jwt, authorization, aws-api-gateway

I am working with HTTP API Gateway with JWT Authorizer. I have got it to work with placing the JWT in the `Authorization` header with the request. However, due to a requirement, I need to be able to place the JWT in the Cookie header instead. I am not able to get the API Gateway to pick a particular cookie inside the Cookie header. I tried the following identity source expressions:

1. $request.header.Cookie.[myCookieName]
2. $request.header.Cookie.myCookieName

None of them worked and I am not sure what else could be done. Does HTTP API version of API gateway supports this? If it does, any suggestions?

The alternate solution would be to use the REST version with a custom authorizer lambda but I do not want to go that route because of another problem not mentioned here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing cookies is currently not possible.

Such a feature request [has been posted on AWS Forums and is in the backlog](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=321664).

Comment: The linked post has been archived iin the re:Post migration due to outdated guidance. I think the answer is still correct based on the current documentation but I don't see dispositive documentation on support (or lack thereof) for cookies. Is anyone able to update this answer to reference an up to date position on cookies as identity sources?